# QTableWidget or QTableView for adding a row?

Tags: qt, qtableview, qtabwidget

I want to make something like a log for TCP packets. And I am trying use QTableWidget, but not sure if that is the right way:

```
    int index = ui->lwHistory->rowCount(); //get index to new row (adding to the end)
    ui->lwHistory->insertRow(index); 
    // Fill the row in that way (think - it's bad way)
    ui->lwHistory->setItem(index, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(startTime.elapsed())));
    ui->lwHistory->setItem(index, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("ETH"));
    ui->lwHistory->setItem(index, 2, new QTableWidgetItem(""));
    ui->lwHistory->setItem(index, 3, new QTableWidgetItem("Connected"));
    ui->lwHistory->setItem(index, 4, new QTableWidgetItem("OK"));
    ui->lwHistory->setRowHeight(0, 20);
```

Now, I want to pass all 5 items like one row with signal `newPacket(...)`, emitted in `class Ethernet` connected to the `onNewPacket(...)` slot in `MainWindow`.

I want to pass only one parameter in the signal because the fields count may increase. Maybe there is right way to pass a row for QTableWidget/QTableView? Do I need use QTableWidget or QTableView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QTableView` (and other Model/View widgets) is preferable for displaying a significant amount of data. It also gives you a lot of flexibility in how the data is displayed/edited.

It's really easy to start with `QStandardItemModel`:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Each data row has 2 properties: string and int
    struct MyData {
        QString str;
        int i;
    };
    QVector<MyData> data = { { "Hello", 1 }, { "World", 2 } };

    // Configure the table view
    auto tv = new QTableView(this);
    auto model = new QStandardItemModel();
    tv->setModel(model);
    this->setCentralWidget(tv);

    // Configure column titles
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem("String Column"));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem("Int Column"));

    // Add rows to the model
    QList<QStandardItem*> rowData;
    Q_FOREACH(const auto &item, data){
        rowData.clear();
        rowData << new QStandardItem(item.str);
        rowData << new QStandardItem(QString("%1").arg(item.i));
        model->appendRow(rowData);
    }
}
```

Implementing your own `QAbstractItemModel` on top of your data will be good for performance. There is a [good tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html) available.

Answer (score 1):

By my experience with Qt, when needed smaller table then QTableWidget is good choice. But if you work on real log which can have for example 100000 lines then better to derive your own model from QAbstractTableModel and your own view from QTableView and override needed functions. 
Imagine that you have large log and your window can display only 50 lines. 
In case of your code you must first allocate and sets all log items, but in case of your own derived classes (in accordance with Qt model/view framework) your derived functions will provide data only for actually displayed 50 items.
Of course it is much more work to implement it.

Comment: Interesting idea. I thinked about 50 records in one window, but i don't know how i can make this. Can you give me advice/link about that?

Comment: In this case your way of adding items into QTableWidget is right: insertRow() followed by allocating QTableWidgetItem passed to setItem() for every column. No special additional magic with it.